# How to identify the list of pipelines attached with a variable group in AzureDevops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

Looking for 2 solutions

- How to identify the list of pipelines attached with a variable group in AzureDevops
  say from the variable group name, i want to understand what are the pipelines (both build and
  release) pipelines refering the values from that VG.
- How to create a secrete variable in the VG using the az command, while creating the VG itself

  az pipelines variable-group create  --name <variable_group_name} --variables myvalue=$myvalue

here its creating normal variable, but I want to create secrete variable in the same coomand above while creating the VG itself.

**Adding the Details as mentioned in the comments**

So here the problem i am facing is

in my curret bash script, we are using the below commands to create variable group and  variable together.

```
az pipelines variable-group create --project=myproject --name $variable_group_name --authorize true --variables mynKey=$my_key
```

So if I want to split this to commands, not sure how I can obtain the group id for the created variable group.

```
az pipelines variable-group create  --project=$projectname --name $variable_group_name --authorize true

az pipelines variable-group variable create --group-id <?????> --name myKey --project=$projectname --secret  true --value $my_key
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to understand what are the pipelines (both build and release) pipelines refering the values from that VG.

We could only list the pipelines which refering variable group based on check the pipeline one by one with the REST API [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). But we could not check the pipeline list based on the variable group.

Details:

- Use the RETS API [Definitions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to list all the pipelines, then we could get all the `definitionId`s.
- Loop use the REST API `Definitions - Get` to get the details info about the pipeline.

  [image]

> How to create a secrete variable in the VG using the az command, while
> creating the VG itself

You could use the az command [az pipelines variable-group create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az_pipelines_variable_group_create) to create a blank variable group at first.

Then use the another az command [az pipelines variable-group variable create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#az_pipelines_variable_group_variable_create) to add the variable with the option `--secret {false, true}`:

```
az pipelines variable-group variable create --group-id
                                            --name
                                            [--org]
                                            [--project]
                                            [--secret {false, true}]
                                            [--subscription]
                                            [--value]
```

Comment: But How we will get the Variable group id here?

Comment: Currently using this command in my basch script .. there its creating variable group and variable with value directly.   "az pipelines variable-group create --project=$projectname --name $variablegroupname --authorize true --variables myKey=$my_key"

Comment: added the details to my question part